# Count individual instances within 2 dates

Tags: sql

We have a a set amount of rooms available, what i need is to count the total of occupation for the rooms within a certain period of time

```
select count (OCCUid) as [Count of occupier],
       sum (datediff(day,Entry_Date,Leave_Date)) as [Count of Instances of stay]
from Tbl_room_activity
where Entry_Date between '01 april 2016' and '31 march 2017'
  and Leave_Date between '01 april 2016' and '31 march 2017'
```

Comment: please provide sample data and expected result for them

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That query uses some product specific functionality.

Comment: Do you store dates in char/varchar columns?

Comment: Give us some sample data, please.

Comment: OCCUID | Entry_Date | Leave_Date |
123456   | 2016/03/01 | 2016/05/01   
123456   | 2016/08/20 | 2016/08/25
123456   | 2017/03/01 | 2017/05/01  
999999   | 2016/03/01 | 2016/05/01   
999999   | 2016/08/20 | 2016/08/25
999999   | 2017/03/01 | 2017/05/01

Comment: OCCUID | Entry_Date | Leave_Date 
===========================
123456   | 2016/03/01 | 2016/05/01   
123456   | 2016/08/20 | 2016/08/25
123456   | 2017/03/01 | 2017/05/01  
999999   | 2016/03/01 | 2016/05/01   
999999   | 2016/08/20 | 2016/08/25
999999   | 2017/03/01 | 2017/05/01
----------------------------------------------